# Powershell starting a process within a loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to write a load balanced powershell publishing script and have seem to hit a roadblock. The foreach loop below will spin up a process to deploy using MSDeploy given the arguments.

```
foreach ($server in $ServersToDeploy) {
    # Spin up a new process
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.FileName = $MSDeploy
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
    $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
    $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $pinfo.Arguments = $arguments
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start() | Out-Null
    $p.WaitForExit()
    $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

    # Output
    if ($stderr) {
        throw $stderr + ("Exit Code: " + $p.ExitCode)
    }
    Write-Host $stdout
}
```

On the first run, it will run the script and execute MSDeploy with the proper arguments, but powershell would indefinitely wait for the first process to exit, but the publish seems to have executed successfully for both servers because when I re-run the command, the process executes quickly and properly for both servers with no changes.

This makes me think that this might be a timing issue, because when the publish goes through fast, it seems to work but when it's slow, it hangs on the first iteration of the publish.

Comment: You have possible deadlock here: `$p.WaitForExit(); $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `ReadToEnd` calls above the `WaitForExit`

```
...
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
$p.WaitForExit()
...
```

Comment: You still have possibility for deadlock. You can stuck at reading `StandardOutput` but process can stuck at writing in `StandardError`.